# How do I have a money Int Be Updated by a Function that is run by a SKAction?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

So I'm trying to have moneyLabel update its text to money: Int's value that is increasing by 'x' amount every second. This is my code, I don't know whats wrong or needed for this to work:

```
    var money: Int = 0

    let moneyLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Futura")
    moneyLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    moneyLabel.fontColor = SKColor.greenColor()
    moneyLabel.fontSize = 24
    moneyLabel.text = "\(money)"

    self.addChild(moneyLabel)



    func MoneyTimer() {

        var money = money + 10


    }

    let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
    let dayTimer = SKAction.sequence([MoneyTimer(), delay])
```

I'm using swift and SpriteKit

Answer (score 1):

`SKAction.runBlock` and `SKAction.repeatActionForever` will help you achieve your goal.

Replace your code with this one :

```
var money: Int = 0

let moneyLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Futura")
moneyLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
moneyLabel.fontColor = SKColor.greenColor()
moneyLabel.fontSize = 24
moneyLabel.text = "\(money)"

self.addChild(moneyLabel)

let moneyTimer = SKAction.runBlock {
    money += 10
    moneyLabel.text = "\(money)"
}

let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
let dayTimer = SKAction.sequence([moneyTimer, delay])
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(dayTimer))
```

On a side note I would change the variable money to be a property of your current class.